# Parity connecting on random outbound ports to IPs and being blocked by Malware Bytes

Tags: parity

I keep getting alerts from Malware bytes that parity is trying to establish outbound connections on random ports to various IPs and these connections are being blocked by Malware bytes. What are these?

[image: Example of malware bytes blocking parity]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can think of the Ethereum blockchain as a big file or database that is constantly being updated. When you use a web browser like Chromium to download a file, the file comes from a single (centralized) provider (though they may have several servers that actually satisfy the request). There is no single canonical information provider for Ethereum which contribute to its decentralized nature. Instead, Ethereum uses peer-to-peer (P2P) technology as found in software like Bittorrent (or, more specifically, the P2P flavour used in [Kademlia](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Kademlia-Peer-Selection)). This means you are constantly exchanging parts of the blockchain with strangers on the Internet to stay up to date. Since each Ethereum node is both a consumer and sharer of the blockchain, there is no need to have a special hosting service for Ethereum: everyone contributes their up and down bandwidth to cooperate to keep the network healthy.

The strangers come from different places and hence have different Internet Protocol (IP) addresses. They might also be behind firewalls or routers that prevent direct connection, so the port number also varies. Thus, in order for your Ethereum node software, Parity, to exchange parts of the blockchain, it needs to connect to different IP addresses and ports. This is expected behaviour. If you let your firewall software block Parity, it will be unable to download the blockchain and you be isolated from the Ethereum network. This means your node will be unable to receive the latest blocks nor will you be able to post transactions through Parity. You should make Parity an exception and allow it through your firewall if you intend on using it in the normal way.